# How to make multiple queries and load into array?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

How would I load multiple Firestore query results into the same array? I am using a for-loop but since Firestore queries are async, the array is set to 0. Here is my code:

```
private void loadMealplans() {
        for (int i = 0; i < restaurantArrayList.size(); i++) {
            Query planQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Meal_Plans").whereEqualTo("restaurantId", restaurantArrayList.get(i).getRestaurantId());
            planQuery.get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot allPlans : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    Mealplan mealplan = allPlans.toObject(Mealplan.class);
                    mealplan.setMealplanId(allPlans.getId());
                    myPlans.add(mealplan);
                }
            });
            Log.d(TAG, "mealplan size:"+ myPlans.size()); // this is always zero
        }
        // Loading data into recycler view
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call [`planQuery.get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#get()) it returns a `Task<QuerySnapshot>`. To wait for multiple tasks to be completed, gather all those tasks and pass them to [`Tasks.whenAll`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#whenAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)).

For more on this, I recommend reading [Become a Firebase task master](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-3_29.html).